# In the Entity class there are two references to the same field in the database

Tags: java, spring

I am studying a training project - working with databases.
Here is a class describing the entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pricelists", schema = "inventories")
public class PriceList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "id_inventory", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long idInventory;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_inventory", nullable = false)
    private Inventory inventory;

    private Integer price;
}
```

And there are two variables that refer to the same "id_inventory" field in the database table. Is it possible to do this? Is this not a mistake?

Answer (score 1):

You should leave that

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "pricelists", schema = "inventories")
public class PriceList {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_inventory", nullable = false)
    private Inventory inventory;

    private Integer price;
}
```

I hope that will work.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem - accept it.